# Fluent UI - best way to import components

Tags: office-fabric, fluentui-react

I'm a beginner in the new Javascript world and would like to know the difference between

```
import { MessageBar } from "office-ui-fabric-react";

import { MessageBar } from "office-ui-fabric-react/lib-commonjs/MessageBar";
```

Both of them seem to work fine. I'm using webpack for creating final JS files. What is the recommended way to import components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both should work. The first one allows you to aggregate all your imports in a single expression.

Note that UI Fabric is deprecated and you should switch to Fluent UI React or Fluent UI React Northstar. So for example your import could look like this:

```
import { DatePicker, MessageBar } from '@fluentui/react';
```

Comment: Thanks @Christophe. Why is it that there are different folders for AMD/CommonJS etc?

Comment: I am no expert here, but I would assume the transpiler will pick one or the other depending on your target (Web, Nodejs, etc.), based on what config options you select.